# Entity Manager not auto increasing ID

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, jpa, h2

I'm trying to run a UT but is failing at the @Before method. This is the error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "UK_PBNJJ4MCIQ51S0SJV9U3J2WQ4_INDEX_5 ON PUBLIC.XACTIVITYCONTENTTYPE(CONTENTTYPE_ID) VALUES (19, 1)"; SQL statement:
insert into XACTIVITYCONTENTTYPE (ACTIVITY_ID, CONTENTTYPE_ID) values (?, ?) [23505-197]
```

I have an array of object(ActivityEntity) which I'm initializing and persisting in a H2 DB:

```
for (int i = 0; i < activities.length; i++) {
            Date createdDate = new Date();

            ActivityEntity activity = new ActivityEntity();
            activity.setType(ActivityType.valueOf(properties.getType()));
            activity.setLabel(ActivityLabel.valueOf(properties.getLabel()));
            activity.setStatus(Status.valueOf(properties.getStatus()));
            activity.setDeliveryType(DeliveryType.valueOf(properties.getDeliveryType()));
            activity.setSubject(em.find(SubjectEntity.class, subjectId));
            activity.setFontSize(FontSize.valueOf(properties.getFontSize()));
            activity.setEstimatedTime(ESTIMATED_TIME);
            activity.setPlannedTime(properties.getPlannedTime());
            activity.setInteractivityType(InteractivityType.valueOf(properties.getInteractivityType()));
            activity.setAudience(Audience.valueOf(properties.getAudience()));
            activity.setPurpose(Purpose.valueOf(properties.getPurpose()));
            activity.setAcademicLevel(AcademicLevel.valueOf(properties.getAcademicLevel()));
            activity.setEnvironment(Environment.valueOf(properties.getEnvironment()));
            activity.setInstructionMethod(InstructionMethod.valueOf(properties.getInstructionMethod()));
            activity.setCreatedBy(CREATED_BY);
            activity.setCreatedDate(createdDate);
            activity.setModifiedBy(CREATED_BY);
            activity.setModifiedDate(createdDate);
            activity.setDeprecated(properties.isDeprecated());
            activity.setTemplate(properties.isTemplate());
            activity.setCurriculumProvider(CurriculumProvider.valueOf(properties.getCurriculumProvider()));
            activity.setShowLessonNavigator(properties.isShowLessonNavigator());
            activity.setShowHeader(properties.isShowHeader());
            activity.setDisplayModuleType(properties.isDisplayModuleType());
            activity.setDisplayLabelType(properties.isDisplayLabelType());
            activity.setShowFooter(properties.isShowFooter());
            activity.setShowPagination(properties.isShowPagination());
            activity.setDisplayProgressBar(properties.isDisplayProgressBar());
            activity.setDisplayResources(properties.isDisplayResources());
            activity.setLanguage(language);
            activity.setPrimaryStatus(PrimaryStatus.valueOf(properties.getPrimaryStatus()));
            activity.setIntendedDeliveryType(IntendedDeliveryType.valueOf(properties.getIntendedDeliveryType()));
            activity.setNextGen(properties.isNextGen());
            activity.setExcludeFromSearch(properties.isExcludeFromSearch());
            activity.setExcludeFromRecommender(properties.isExcludeFromRecommender());
            activity.setTeacherCreated(properties.isTeacherCreated());
            activity.setTitle(TITLE + (i + 1), language);
            activity.getGrades().addAll(grades);
            activity.getStudentGroupings().add(new StudentGroupingEntity(properties.getStudentGroupingId()));
            activity.getPedagogicalIntents().add(new PedagogicalIntentEntity(properties.getPedagogicalIntentId()));
            activity.getLearnerTypes().add(new LearnerTypeEntity(properties.getLearnerTypeId()));
            activity.getContentTypes().add(new ContentTypeEntity(properties.getContentTypeId()));

            activities[i] = em.persist(activity);
        }
        em.flush();
```

The last set it's the property related to the error. The properties have a value of 19 for the ContentTypeId. Now, this is part of the Activity entity class:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ACTIVITY")
    public class ActivityEntity {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SQ_ACTIVITY_ACTIVITY_ID")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "SQ_ACTIVITY_ACTIVITY_ID", sequenceName = "SQ_ACTIVITY_ACTIVITY_ID", allocationSize = 1)
        @Column(name = "ACTIVITY_ID")
        private Integer id;
    
//MORE FIELDS LEFT OUT FOR CLARITY

    @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "XACTIVITYCONTENTTYPE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ACTIVITY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ACTIVITY_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CONTENTTYPE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID") } )
        private List<ContentTypeEntity> contentTypes = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And here's the ContentTypeEntity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTENTTYPE")
public class ContentTypeEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "SEQ_NUM")
    private int seqNum;
    
    public ContentTypeEntity() {
        
    }
    
    public ContentTypeEntity(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSeqNum() {
        return seqNum;
    }

    public void setSeqNum(int seqNum) {
        this.seqNum = seqNum;
    }
    
}
```

If I debug, the ids for ActivityEntity is being generated correctly for each of the 3 objects that i'm putting in the array (ids=[1,2,3]). So i don't understand why the second insert is using the id=1, which is what the exception is implying. If I put one ActivityEntity in the array, everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't pasted in all the code and you cannot assign the return type of em.persist, but i think the issue is probably related to creating multiple instances of contenttype with id 19.

Assuming content type with id 19 is already persisted and you are attempting to just create references to it rather than persist it as you have no cascade in your ManyToMany you  can do something like this as this sample test code shows. The transaction are there as I don't know your tx boundaries in your code and just for the purpose of saving the contenttype separately

```
    @Test
    public void saveActivities() {
        // Tx1 - Persist content type

        EntityTransaction tx1 = em.getTransaction();
        tx1.begin();

        ContentTypeEntity contentType = new ContentTypeEntity(19);
        em.persist(new ContentTypeEntity(19));

        tx1.commit();

        em.detach(contentType);

        // Tx2 - Persist activities using a reference to content type

        EntityTransaction tx2 = em.getTransaction();
        tx2.begin();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            ActivityEntity activity = new ActivityEntity();
            activity.getContentTypes().add(em.getReference(ContentTypeEntity.class, 19));

            em.persist(activity);
        }

        tx2.commit();

        // assertions
    }
```